# How can I progmatically create a flat parent child table from an alphanumeric range?

Tags: sql, vb.net, algorithm, peoplesoft

I've pulled some hierarchy data from a PeopleSoft table which includes alphanumeric ranges from and to for the leaf values. This I assume allows for quick entry, a catch all and is reasonably optimal for space consumption.

I need to break that down though so that I have every combination in a flat format. If it were simply numeric I could just loop through the data set adding one from the upper to the lower bound, but with alpha numeric it is more difficult than that.

I assume that Peoplesoft is using ASCii to order the possible characters but could be wrong.

Does anybody know of a reasonably quick way of doing what I need?

Current data format:

```
SETID,SETCNTRLVALUE,TREE_NAME,EFFDT,TREE_NODE_NUM,RANGE_FROM,RANGE_TO,TREE_BAANCH,DYNAMIC_RANGE,OLD_TREE_NODE_NUM,LEAF_IMAGE
AAAS10, ,S_DEPTS,2016-04-05 00:00:00.000,1499992131,Z870,Z870, ,N,N, 
AAAS10, ,S_DEPTS,2016-04-05 00:00:00.000,1499992131,Z880,Z880, ,N,N, 
AAAS10, ,S_DEPTS,2016-04-05 00:00:00.000,1499992131,Z881,Z881, ,N,N, 
AAAS10, ,S_DEPTS,2016-04-05 00:00:00.000,1499999761,Z850,Z850, ,N,N, 
AAAS10, ,S_DEPTS,2016-04-05 00:00:00.000,1499999761,Z950,Z950, ,N,N, 
AAAS10, ,S_DEPTS,2016-04-05 00:00:00.000,1499999761,Z951,Z999, ,N,N,
```

Required output format:

```
1499992131,Z870
1499992131,Z880
1499992131,Z881 
1499999761,Z850
1499999761,Z950
1499999761,Z951
1499999761,Z952
1499999761,Z953
...
1499999761,Z998
1499999761,Z999
```

TREE_NODE_NUM,LEAF

Probably worth calling out that the from and to fields can take any form and can't be relied upon to be a1234 etc

Comment: There is a tree flattener utility in PeopleSoft which puts the tree into a denormalized table for reporting.  You may be able to get the results you want easier by using that table.  I believe though it would only show valid departments in the range.  EG if the range is 1-5 and only departments 2 and 4 are in the department table, the tree flattened table would only have entries for 2 and 4.

Comment: I've tried the tree flattener tool, but unfortunately it runs to no success. I do think that this could be what we need.

Answer (score 0):

I use a UDF to create dynamic ranges, but a Numbers (or tally) will do the trick as well

The sub-query generates ALL combinations of [A-Z] and [000-999] or 26,000 rows.  Again you could have a Letters Table [A-Z], and a Numbers table [000-999].  Then you can (as the sub-query)

```
Select Letter+Padded_Number from Letters A Join Numbers B on 1=1
```

Sample Data and Sample Query

```
Declare @Table table (Tree_Node_Num varchar(25),Range_From varchar(25),Range_To varchar(25))
Insert Into @Table values 
('1499992131','Z870','Z870'),
('1499992131','Z880','Z880'),
('1499992131','Z881','Z881'),  
('1499999761','Z850','Z850'),
('1499999761','Z951','Z999')

Select Distinct 
       Tree_Node_Num
      ,NewStr
From  @Table A
Join (
        Select NewStr=Alpha+PadNum
         From (Select Cntr=cast(RetVal as int),PadNum=format(RetVal,'000') from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](0,999,1)) A
         Join (Select RetVal,Alpha=char(RetVal) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](65,90,1)) B
           on 1=1
     ) B
 On B.NewStr Between A.Range_From and A.Range_To
 Order by 1,2
```

Returns

```
Tree_Node_Num   NewStr
1499992131      Z870
1499992131      Z880
1499992131      Z881
1499999761      Z850
1499999761      Z951
1499999761      Z952
1499999761      Z953
...
1499999761      Z997
1499999761      Z998
1499999761      Z999
```

The UDF, Just in case, but again a numbers/tally table will do the trick as well

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number] (@R1 money,@R2 money,@Incr money)

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](0,100,2)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal money)

As
Begin
    With NumbTable as (
        Select NumbFrom = @R1
        union all
        Select nf.NumbFrom + @Incr
        From NumbTable nf
        Where nf.NumbFrom < @R2
    )
    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal)

    Select NumbFrom from NumbTable Option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End
```

Comment: Does this assume that the format is always 3 numbers prefixed with a letter? unfortunately that isn't the case with the real data just the example I've given above. In some cases there are 8 characters ... so the number of combinations will be huge?

Comment: Easy enough to adjust.  Perhaps you should have posted a more representative example